# AngularJS - Binding to a provider properties

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

is it possible to bind the date from an serviceProvider with $watch?

My question is can i bind data from an provider service to my view?
I try to bind the $get object from a provide in my view because the provider is loaded in the init phase, without an controller.

I try it on this way but i get no updates.
http://plnkr.co/edit/t3PrE6lX1EDIMuqKyTW0?p=preview

```
    <body ng-app="ServiceNotification">
    <div style="border-style:dotted" ng-controller="TimerCtrl1">
        TimerCtrl1<br/>
        Last Updated: {{lastUpdated}}<br/>
        Last Updated: {{calls}}<br/>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("ServiceNotification", []);

    function TimerCtrl1($scope, Timer) {
        $scope.$watch(function () { return Timer.data; }, function (data){
          console.log("In $watch - data:" + data);
          $scope.lastUpdated = data.lastUpdated;
          $scope.calls = data.calls;
       }, true); // <-- don't forgt the true
    };

    app.provider("Timer", function () {

      this.$get = function() {
        var data = { lastUpdated: new Date(), calls: 0 };

            var updateTimer = function () {
            data.lastUpdated = new Date();
            data.calls += 1;
            console.log("updateTimer: " + data.lastUpdated);

            window.setTimeout(updateTimer, 5000);
        };
        updateTimer();

        return {
            data: data
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

Thanks Thomas

Comment: Please post your code here, if the link will expire, or will become unaccessable, the question will have less sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get no updates cause setTimeout callback is called out of the digest cycle. There is a special `$timeout` wrapper in angular ([http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout)), which you can inject into you `$get` provider method.

```
app.provider("Timer", function () {  
  this.$get = function($timeout) {
    var data = { lastUpdated: new Date(), calls: 0 };

    var updateTimer = function () {
        data.lastUpdated = new Date();
        data.calls += 1;
        console.log("updateTimer: " + data.lastUpdated);
        $timeout(updateTimer, 5000);
    };
    updateTimer();

    return {
        data: data
    }
  }
});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/QUVuSnikIwVd3TocU7Vn?p=preview